# Azure Pricing Clarification - Instances

Tags: azure, instances, sni

I am looking to move my websites from sitting on an Azure VM to being in an App Service.

In the App service there are several items in the Pricing I don't understand and cannot find answers too. Do you know what these items means?

"Up to 10 Instances" Auto Scale. Does this means I can host 10 apps on this plan, or that it will create new instances for my individual apps when under load? IE if my website google.com was being used a lot, would 10 instances of this website spin up?

5 SNI, 1IP - What on earth does this mean?

Thanks!
Tom

Answer (score 3):

Auto Scale means that the Azure will automatically create instances or shutdown them, based on your website traffic. So your second example is correct.

5SNI (Server Name Indication) or 1IP, I'm just gonna explanation copy and paste from Azure documentation website ([here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/)) as I believe it's explained quite well:

> **IP** based SSL associates a certificate with a domain name by mapping the dedicated public IP address of the server to the domain name. This requires each domain name (contoso.com, fabricam.com, etc.) associated with your service to have a dedicated IP address. This is the traditional method of associating SSL certificates with a web server.
>
> **SNI** based SSL is an extension to SSL and Transport Layer Security (TLS) that allows multiple domains to share the same IP address, with separate security certificates for each domain. Most modern browsers (including Internet Explorer, Chrome, Firefox and Opera) support SNI, however older browsers may not support SNI. For more information on SNI, see the Server Name Indication article on Wikipedia.

Comment: In addition to @Jaka's excellent answer, please see this link to understand more about SNI and IP in the context of your question - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/ (Read `SSL Connections` section).